# How can I get a clicked table row's TBODY?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table with a few rows in it. Each row has an `onclick` event that is supposed to check the ID of the `tbody` element. This is stored in a variable for later use in a function.

Right now I have this snippet of jQuery:

`var parentTable = $(this.parentNode)[0].id;`

However, this only gets the ID of the *entire* table, not the `tbody`.

**What's the best way to specify the ID of the `tbody` element?**

Comment: can you show us your html structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your use of jQuery is wasted there. It would be written like this:

```
var parentTable = this.parentNode.id;
```

As far as getting the `tbody` id, assuming `this` is actually the row, your code should do it.

If you're actually getting the table, then that would be very unusual. The only way a `tbody` would not get created would be if you manually created the table from DOM creation methods, and left it out.

Comment: This is correct, the OP shouldn't have any issues using that code. I made a jsFiddle that works using this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xymwsbz4/

Comment: This worked - I figured out that my `this` wasn't the row, but the `tbody` instead!

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to store that information in a data-tbody-id for each row, then when the user clicks on the row, the event object will hold that information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
var tobody = parentTable.children('tbody')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function

```
var tbody = $(this).parents("tbody");
var id = tbody.attr("id");
```